# Laravel Homestead not working database connect

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I have installed laravel homestead and run it.

But I can't run migration locally and in vagrant.

If I try to run the migration inside vagrant

```
cd ~/code/project/
php artisan migrate
```

I got an error

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 54320?"
```

If I try to run the migration locally I got a another error

```
PDOException::("could not find driver")
```

my .env file contains the same code as written in doc

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=54320
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Maybe something I do not understand but do I need posgresql locally and inside my vagrant? Where I have to work with database locally or with vagrant?

Comment: Change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost`

Comment: now working ( could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost"

Comment: Change your database , username and password credentials as per your database

Comment: i am using the same username and password wich are i am using for connect from phpstorm

http://joxi.ru/nAynW7asYODkBr

but this is not working

http://joxi.ru/Dr8dQbGF4V9Dbr